# ClassNotFoundException seek bar preference

Tags: android, settings, android-manifest, seekbar, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to implement a seek bar preference into my live wallpaper settings. The problem is that I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException`.

I created a subclass ([which can be viewed here](http://android.hlidskialf.com/blog/code/android-seekbar-preference)) to create the seekbar then added the following to my wallpaper_settings.xml

```
<custom.android.mypackage.SeekBarPreference 
    android:title="XXXXXXXXX"
    android:summary="XXXXXXXXXXX"
    android:key="duration"
    android:dialogMessage="Something duration"
    android:defaultValue="5"
    android:text=" minutes"
    android:max="100"
    />
```

My SeekBarPreference.java class is in the same package as my main Activity. Is there something I need to add to my manifest file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="custom.android.mypackage"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper" 
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
    </service>
     <activity android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/wallpaper_settings"            
        android:name=".WallpaperSettings"/> 
  <activity
        android:name=".SeekBarPreference" 
android:label="@string/wallpaper_settings" /> 
</application>
```

```
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):  
Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: custom.android.mypackage.SeekBarPreference in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/custom.android.mypackage-2.apk]
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
11-11 12:32:37.308: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8419):     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SeekBarPreference is customView not activity . so

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SeekBarPreference" 
android:label="@string/wallpaper_settings" />
```

can not find it . remove it from menifest

Comment: uninstall app . clean and build then run . sometimed wrongly saved older values crete such problem

Comment: I created a new android application and copied over all the same files and it worked perfectly! thanks